# Causality example execution

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, concurrency

The link gives an example of allowed legal execution. Please refer to page 26 section 4.8.1 http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.629&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

The example is

```
Initially,
x = y = 0
Thread 1  Thread 2
r1 = x;   r2 = y;
y = 1;    x = r2;
r1 == r2 == 1 is a legal behavior
```

From paper,

> We wish the action
>   r2 = y
>   to see the value 1.
>   C
>   1
>   cannot contain this action
>   seeing this value: neither write to
>   y
>   had been committed.
>   C
>   2
>   may contain this
>   action; however, the read of
>   y
>   must return 0 in
>   E
>   2
>   , because of Rule 6. Execution
>   E
>   2
>   is therefore identical to
>   E
>   1
>   
>  
>   In
>   E
>   3
>   , by Rule 7,
>   r2 = y
>   can see any conflicting write that occurs in
>   C
>   2
>   (as long
>   as that write is happens-before consistent). This action can now see the write of 1
>   to
>   y
>   in Thread 1, which was committed in
>   C
>   1
>   . We commit one additional action in
>   C
>   3
>   : a write of 1 to
>   x
>   by
>   x = r2
>   .

We can't commit r2=y where value of y is 1 because read of y will return 0 according to rule 6. But according to the paper in the next commit cycle in E3, r2=y can see the value y=1 which is committed in Thread1. 
My doubt is execution E3 for committing r2=y should also satisfy the rule 6 and should only see the value happened before it, that is the x=0. Why is that in E2 because of rule 6 while committing r2=y, y can only read y value as 0 but in E3 while committing r2=y, y can read the y=1 written in Thread1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to note is that Rule 7 allows a read committed in *C<sub>i</sub>* to see different write in *E<sub>i</sub>* than the one it sees in *E*. However this Schrödinger's read must be resolved sooner rather than later. Rule 5 ensures that such a read must see the same writes in *E<sub>i + 1</sub>* as in *E*.

So if you want a read to see a racing write, you can't have that in the same execution in which these two are committed. You need to wait for the next execution, and you need to make sure that the racing write does not violate happens-before ordering (in our example, mostly the happens-before ordering of `y = 0` and `r2 = y`).

So you commit the read `r2 = y` in *C<sub>2</sub>* and in *E<sub>2</sub>* it sees only the write `y = 0` because that write happens-before it, but in *E<sub>3</sub>*, `r2 = y` can see the racing write with which it couldn't establish happens-before.

P.S. This reasoning is explained in the paper for the read `r1 = x` a couple of sentences below:

> *C<sub>4</sub>*, as part of *E<sub>4</sub>*, contains the read `r1 = x`; it still sees 0, because of Rule 6. In
>   our final execution *E* = *E<sub>5</sub>*, however, Rule 7 allows `r1 = x` to see the write of 1 to `x` that was committed in *C<sub>3</sub>*.